# WSO2 API Manager - Publisher : Is it possible to update the base context path of an API after creation?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a couple of APIs that have been published in the API Manager that needs to have their base context paths updated. The current implementation of the publisher does not allow the user to do that.

I tried to unpublishing the API and tried to edit the swagger file but no luck. Is this an intended feature? In which case I understand the need for it as Clients won't be affected by unnecessary context path updates or is there a way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the context of an API for the same reason you have mentioned. So the only way is to creating a new API with the new context and remove the existing APIs if they are not required to be used by consumers.

Answer (score 3):

You can update API context using below method.

1. Login to carbon console as admin user and go to /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider
2. Select API provider (eg: admin)
3. Select API
4. Select version
5. Go to api, please refer below image

[image]

6. Then you can update API details as below,
   [image]

7. Then go to API publisher portal and save and publish the API.

You can verify it by looking at am_api table and syanpse file

Comment: On the step 1, once you logged in, open the resources tab, there's a browse/search option